# "later" or "after" + "time period" in a sentence that talks about something unchanged, repeatedly happening, etc...?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

Can we use "later" or "after" in a sentence that talks about something unchanged, repeatedly happening, etc...?

**Example 1**

> A: The weather here is usually sunny, but it can change suddenly. You wake up and see the weather is nice. **A few hours later**, the weather can be gloomy or rainy.

**Example 2**

> A: The weather here is usually sunny, but it can change suddenly. You wake up and see the weather is nice. **After a few hours**, the weather can be gloomy or rainy.

**Example 3**

> A: The weather here is usually sunny, but it can change suddenly. When I wake up, I can see the weather is nice. **A few hours later**, the weather can be gloomy or rainy.

**Example 4**

> A: The weather here is usually sunny, but it can change suddenly. When I wake up, I can see the weather is nice. **After a few hours**, the weather can be gloomy or rainy.

Comment: You can use either, or 'in a few hours'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ‘later’ or ‘after’ can still be used when something is repeatedly happening. It is still sometimes gloomy and rainy after it is nice and sunny. ‘after (something)’ means it is happening in a future time frame from the something.